# material-component-datetime-picker-You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

I have tried to use the material-component-datetime-picker according to the documentation and following information contain about the environment.

Angular

Angular version : 10.1.0

material version : 10.1.0

angular-material-components/moment-adapter - 4.0.1

angular-material-components/datetime-picker - 4.0.2

Following is the code block to view datetime picker.

```
<mat-form-field> <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="tab._from" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [disabled]="disabled"> <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"> </mat-datepicker-toggle> <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="showSpinners" [showSeconds]="showSeconds" [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond" [touchUi]="touchUi" [color]="color"> </ngx-mat-datetime-picker> </mat-form-field>
```

When I try to load the page, datetime-picker appears but following error appears on console.

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27) at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11) at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59) at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:53) at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36) at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49) at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:3) at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42) at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28) at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:21)
```

[image]

TS File

```
export class Picker {
   @ViewChild('fromPicker') fromPicker: any;
  @ViewChild('toPicker') toPicker: any;

  public date: moment.Moment;
  public disabled = false;
  public showSpinners = true;
  public showSeconds = false;
  public touchUi = false;
  public enableMeridian = false;
  public minDate: moment.Moment;
  public maxDate: moment.Moment;
  public stepHour = 1;
  public stepMinute = 1;
  public stepSecond = 1;
  public color: ThemePalette = 'primary';

  public stepHours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  public stepMinutes = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
  public stepSeconds = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
}
```

Seems like the error is related to picker that we use.

Any reason or any missing dependencies?

Comment: `[ngxMatDatetimePicker]` it's not material-angular

Comment: @Eliseo Yes. Thats deprecated and If you visit this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker, this package is what I am using,Implementation is done using that

Comment: having the exact issue

Comment: @CharlieNorris ohh..Did you find anything yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating @angular-material-components/datetime-picker to version **4.0.3** worked for me.
The update was released a few hours ago
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker

Comment: It strangely works specifically with @angular/material @10.2.1

Comment: Its not working even with 4.0.3. `http://prntscr.com/12gpnwy` please help

Answer (score 2):

In version 4.0.3 worked for me too. Update your package.

Answer (score 1):

For angular v11 upgrade @angular-material-components/datetime-picker to v 5.1.0 which fixes this bug

Comment: Yes thanks. It does disappear after upgrading to v11.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using  *ngx-mat-datetime-picker* which is wrapper plugin for angular material datepicker:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-datetime-picker

Implementation looks good, though error must be coming because you are not passing the expected value with proper type in attributes. Some component property is being undefined which you are passing to attribute.
you can revisit the demo implementation and check if you are sending the right values:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Double checked. This error comes when I enable 
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker #fromPicker [showSpinners]="showSpinners" [showSeconds]="showSeconds"
              [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond" >
            </ngx-mat-datetime-picker> 
section

Comment: can you share the output image, because replacing your [formcontrol] with mine worked using your code :
            <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="pickern" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="myControl"
              [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [disabled]="disabled">

Comment: I have updated the question with the output error console. Calendar appears with the above error

Comment: I have updated the question with the code section from TS file.I have added the necessary part of the datepicker

Comment: code you have added is correct, must be some other part of TS file causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem
Angular 11.1.0
Material 11.1.0
datetime-picker: 5.0.3

I've managed to isolate the problem somewhat, it occurs here:

```
    _watchStateChanges() {
        const datepickerStateChanged = this.datepicker ? this.datepicker.stateChanges : of();
        const inputStateChanged = this.datepicker && this.datepicker.datepickerInput ?
            this.datepicker.datepickerInput.stateChanges : of();
        const datepickerToggled = this.datepicker ?
            merge(this.datepicker.openedStream, this.datepicker.closedStream) :
            of();
        this._stateChanges.unsubscribe();
        this._stateChanges = merge(this._intl.changes, datepickerStateChanged, inputStateChanged, datepickerToggled).subscribe(() => this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
    }
```

For some reason, datepickerStateChanged is undefined here. Which is what causes the problems further down the line. No idea why yet though. If anyone has more of an answer then that, that would be awesome. For now, I'm gonna file this as a bug.

Already in there it seems:
https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/94

They suggest downgrading to 4.0.3, which is what I'll be trying tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `[for]="picker"` in your HTML.
For me the issue was resolved by removing that.

Comment: Your datepicker toggle will not work if You will remove it