# angular material date-time picker - Throwing an error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting an error logged to console when I implemented angular material datetime picker using. But it works fine except that my tests failed because of the error.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="auto" class="date-picker">
    <mat-label>From Date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="fromDatePicker" name="fromDate" [(ngModel)]="fromDate"
         placeholder="From Date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #fromDatePicker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="false"
         [stepHour]="1" [stepMinute]="10" [touchUi]="false">
    </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
</mat-form-field>

ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, 
Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:3)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:21)
```

Comment: Can you tell, are you of which version of `angular` and `ngx-mat-datetime-picker` at now ? You can check it by looking at package.json file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [material-component-datetime-picker-You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805438/material-component-datetime-picker-you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-e)

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to compatibility issue, which can be resolved by installing the appropriate version of `@angular-material-components/datetime-picker` corresponding to your core Angular version.

I struggled with the same issue but resolved it by just importing the right version of this package .

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932554/13834563